# How to Dynamically Create Variables in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I would like to manipulate the variables names. (Just like in PHP you use `${}` to create dynamic variables). For exemple:

I want to create N variables with A_N as their name:

```
for i = 1:N
  A_i = 'new variable!';
end
```

The result would be:

```
A_1
A_2
...
A_N
```

Comment: If you clarify what kinds of variables you have, or how you plan to use it, I can further clarify my answer.

Comment: Did my answer not work for you or should I clarify?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know about dynamic variables, but the **generally accepted way** to store dynamic content without structure is to use cells instead of new variable names. You can store any type within each element of the cell,. You can even store cells within cells! You would use the code below.

```
A = cell(i,1);
for i = 1:N
    A{i} = 'new variable!';
end
```

Then you can access the "dynamic variable" using:

```
A{1}
```

If you're looking for a more complex structure, you could consider structs as well. To clarify, this is not the struct method of how @Tony described but as a built in [structured array](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/struct.html).

Answer (score 10):

If you want to create variables programmatically (not a recommended practice, but if you insist), see the previous question:  [A way to dynamically create variables in Matlab?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24759942/a-way-to-dynamically-create-variables-in-matlab).

As I say, it's messy to do that, and at least you may want to have things stored within a structure, which allows programmatic creation of elements using string variables and dynamic referencing using the paren syntax.  For instance, in your example, you could use:

```
N = 5;
for i = 1:N
    fieldname = sprintf('A_%i', i);
    s.(fieldname) = 'new variable!';
end
```

If you then display the structure `s`, you will see:

```
>> s
s = 
A_1: 'new variable!'
A_2: 'new variable!'
A_3: 'new variable!'
A_4: 'new variable!'
A_5: 'new variable!'
```

Comment: This is VERY tedious to initiate and use. Using my method would be much easier, unless there's a really specific reason not to (and I can't imagine why there would be).

Comment: It's not hard to do at all, since you can easily reference the struct with the string name.  If it's important to have human-readable names for the references for the values, a struct works well.  A cell array is nice, but provides only an index value, not a name for reference.  That said, dynamic names for structs can be dangerous.

Comment: I agree that human readable names is a good thing, but that generally conflicts with the ability to vectorize code effectively thus hampering performance right? Additionally, wouldn't it generally increase maintenance effort? Again I don't see a case where it would be useful unless readability is so high in priority that everything else doesn't matter. Proper commenting would resolve ambiguity.

Comment: Agreed, dynamic names are almost certainly a bad idea in general.  But if you want them, you want them.  No accounting for the crazy ideas we have in designing programs.

Comment: Perhaps like @brodroll mentioned in [his answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29812867/802378), you could append that "it's not good practice"

Comment: Dire warnings about dynamic variable creation have been added to the answer.  Dynamic structure referencing has its own dangers, but it's clearer than dynamic variable creation.  It's possible to test for the existence of fields before access, and it's a very handy way to create a string/value storage system.  It can be quite elegant and useful.

Comment: @rayryeng ohh interesting why's that?

Comment: @krisdestruction - Because I can associate real variable names with something.  With cell arrays, you have to use numeric indexes.  Though sometimes numeric variables are merited, I need to associate an actual variable name with something.

Comment: @rayryeng there are times doesn't sound like always ;) I see, are you talking about a sequential variables in variable storage or are you talking about unrelated names?

Comment: @rayryeng Ah okay I just wanted to clarify as I thought you had some magical case other than readability that you ingeniously thought of haha

Comment: @krisdestruction - oh no lol.  Just a preference really.  No other magical cases or fairy dust here.  I've +1ed your answer too as it's a valid approach.

Answer (score 3):

You could achieve a dynamic creation of variables using the function *eval*, but it is not good practice. I'd strongly encourage using cells or structures as others pointed out. But if this is what you're after:

```
for i=1:N
    eval(sprintf('A_%d = %d',i,i));
end
```

This will create A_1 = 1, A_2 = 2 and so forth.

Comment: I normally do not vote on `eval` answers, but because you disclosed that it isn't good practice, I have decided to make an exception. +1.

Comment: Thanks. I normally wouldn't propose a solution with eval either, but it was the closest thing I could think of to ${} in php