# How to change name ( add index ) of variable in Maltab?

Tags: matlab

I have the following script:

```
a=[1,2,3]
for i=1:length(a)
  e=0;
  e1=0;
  e2=0;
..... 

end
```

In the script the main loop ( the first ) is  `for i=1:length(a)`. `e`,`e1`,`e2` should being rewritten for each `a(i)` as:

```
% I count the error
a=1:  e=0;
      e1=0;
      e2=0;
a=2:  e=0;
      e1=0;
      e2=0;
a=3:  e=0;
      e1=0;
      e2=0;
```

Accorsing to my first script, Matlab rewrites `e`,`e1`,e2`, but I need`e`,`e1`,e2` for each `a(i)`.

Question: Is it possible to change name of variables for each `a(i)`?

```
% to change like this?
a=1:  e_a_1=0;
      e1_a_1=0;
      e2_a_1=0;
a=2:  e_a_2=0;
      e1_a_2=0;
      e2_a_2=0;
a=3:  e_a_2=0;
      e1_a_2=0;
      e2_a_2=0;
```

Comment: Note that this is [bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32467170/2586922)

Comment: Don't use single variables please! Use a cell (kind of array), see this nice answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29812747/1749882

Comment: You want to use `e(i)`, `e1(i)`, etc.